# Why does SQLite in memory returns different result when using AsNoTracking?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I was writing tests using SQLite in-memory database with XUnit and ASP.NET Core 3.1 and found strange behavior.

Lets say that we have User model and we want to change property IsActive to false:

```
var u = new User {Id = Guid.NewGuid(), IsActive = true};
_db.Users.Add(u);
_db.SaveChanges();
u.IsActive = false;

// Returns false
var isActive = _db.Users.Single(x => x.Id == u.Id).IsActive;

// Returns true
var isActiveNoTracking = _db.Users.AsNoTracking().Single(x => x.Id == u.Id).IsActive;

// Fails.
Assert.Equal(isActive, isActiveNoTracking);
```

I get different result depending if AsNoTracking() is called or not. Why is this happening? Isn't AsNoTracking() supposed to stop tracking changes made on fetched object, not to mess with data that was already changed?

If I call SaveChanges() after changing the property then it is all good (as expected):

```
var u = new User {Id = Guid.NewGuid(), IsActive = true};
_db.Users.Add(u);
_db.SaveChanges();
u.IsActive = false;
_db.SaveChanges();

// Returns false
var isActive = _db.Users.Single(x => x.Id == u.Id).IsActive;

// Returns false
var isActiveNoTracking = _db.Users.AsNoTracking().Single(x => x.Id == u.Id).IsActive;

// Success.
Assert.Equal(isActive, isActiveNoTracking);
```

So I am confused, I'm not sure when SQLite in-memory actually commits changes. Sometimes you can fetch changes from db without calling SaveChanges() but sometimes you cannot.

Here is code related to db

```
    public class SqliteInMemoryAppDbContext : AppDbContext
    {
        public SqliteInMemoryAppDbContext(IConfiguration configuration) : base(configuration)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        {
            var connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");
            connection.Open();
            options.UseSqlite(connection);
        }
    }

// I create db context for each test like this and dispose it after each test.
var _db = new SqliteInMemoryAppDbContext(null);
_db.Database.EnsureDeleted();
_db.Database.EnsureCreated();
```

Comment: It's not clear how the first and second code fragment are related. Are they in the same scope? Also, I suppose that all `[0]` indexes end up returning the same user, but you don't make that explicit. Anyway, calling a query with `AsNoTracking()` doesn't un-track *already tracked* entities in the context, as you seem to expect.

Comment: @GertArnold Yes, it's all in the same scope and it is the same user. I don't expect that but that is what is happening. As you can see in the example, same entity is fetched differently from database depending if you call it with or without AsNoTracking().

Comment: You better show consistent, complete pieces of code. I still wonder how `deactivatedUser` should be the same user as the one in `ToList()[0]` if you don't save created users.

Comment: @GertArnold Yes, I wonder that too. That is why I asked this question :) If I have time I will prepare project with single example and put it on the GitHub.

Comment: @GertArnold I added code showing how users are created. I think that it is quite obvious now.

Comment: @GertArnold I simplified my example a lot now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I am confused, I'm not sure when SQLite in-memory actually commits changes. Sometimes you can fetch changes from db without calling SaveChanges() but sometimes you cannot.

This is impossible. In order for something to be saved to the DB you need to call `SaveChanges`. What happens here is that you see local objects and you assume that they are stored in your DB. I generally suggest that you use a a DB query tool to learn how it works because it can be difficult at first.

Entity Framework has some local objects that it stores. For example at your first query.

```
// returns true, because it checks the db due to no tracking
_db.Users.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.IsActive).OrderBy(x=>x.Username).ToList()[0].IsActive
// returns false, it finds the local reference
_db.Users.Where(x => x.IsActive).OrderBy(x=>x.Username).ToList()[0].IsActive
```

As you can see from the comments above it has different behavior based on the commands. It's not about when changes are saved to the db. This happens only if you call `SaveChanges`. What you are confused is for when the 'queries' you write with EF look at the DB or locally.

Generally for SQL at least I like to work with SQL profiler to see what queries EF sends to the Database. For example in your case you will have a query with where and order by send to the db.

EDIT:

About how to understand when the db is called or not i suggest reading [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/how-query-works).

To summarize AsNoTracking always creates the new entity which means that it will look in the db for it. Instead the other commands in your example first look locally for the object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I tell when EF will call database and when it will use local data from memory? I was expecting that every time I call _db.Users I am hitting the database (it looks like it does when using Postgres). But with SQLite in memory I can't tell source of the data anymore.

Comment: I simplified my example.